# String replace function in Idris

Tags: string, replace, idris

In Idris, strings are primitives, not lists like they are in Haskell. Thus, I would expect there to be some sort of primitive `replace : (needle : String) -> (replacement : String) -> (haystack : String) -> String` function a la [`Data.Text.replace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:replace). I have not been able to find this. But I thought, perhaps I will be able to find some `replace : Eq a => (needle : List a) -> (replacement : List a) -> (haystack : List a) -> List a` function a la [`Data.List.Utils.replace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.2.0.0/docs/Data-List-Utils.html#v%3areplace), since Idris does provide `unpack : String -> List Char` and `pack : Foldable t => t Char -> String`. However, I have not been able to find `replace` for Lists defined in Idris, either. I have searched the documentation and the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev) for several things and poked around with `:browse` in the REPL, but all to no luck. Of course, good old Idris' `replace` function is for working on types, not strings... (this makes me very happy at one level but does not solve my problem).

Finally, I have ported `Data.List.Utils.replace` over from Haskell, but I wonder about its performance, and much worse, it is not total. Also, it takes a surprisingly large amount of code for what I normally would think of as a primitive operation (given that strings are primitives).

```hs
    spanList : (List a -> Bool) -> List a -> (List a, List a)
    spanList _ [] = ([],[])
    spanList func list@(x::xs) =
      if func list
      then
        let (ys,zs) = spanList func xs
        in (x::ys,zs)
      else ([],list)

    breakList : (List a -> Bool) -> List a -> (List a, List a)
    breakList func = spanList (not . func)

    partial
    split : Eq a => List a -> List a -> List (List a)
    split _ [] = []
    split delim str =
      let (firstline, remainder) = breakList (isPrefixOf delim) str in
      firstline :: case remainder of
                        [] => []
                        x => if x == delim
                             then [] :: []
                             else split delim (drop (length delim) x)

    partial
    strReplace : String -> String -> String -> String
    strReplace needle replacement =
      pack . intercalate (unpack replacement) . split (unpack needle) . unpack
```

I am going to reshape this until I get it total because I see no reason why it couldn't be made total, but in the meantime, what am I missing? Do people really do so little string manipulation in Idris that this is not available at all? I would assume that there would at least be something in `contrib`. How do you do string replacement in Idris?

Comment: Strings are not "that" primitive in the C backend. Indeed event the standard C library does not have a built-in string replace function AFAIK, so that is probably the reason why the function does not exist yet. I also could find anything in the idris libraries so you are probably on the right track to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who finds this later, wanting an implementation, here is what I have at this point:

```
module ListExt

%default total
%access public export

splitOnL' : Eq a => (delim : List a)    -> {auto dprf : NonEmpty delim   }
                 -> (matching : List a) -> {auto mprf : NonEmpty matching}
                 -> List a -> (List a, List (List a))
splitOnL' _ _ [] = ([], [])
splitOnL' delim m@(_::m') list@(x::xs) =
  if isPrefixOf m list
  then
    case m' of
      [] => ([], uncurry (::) $ splitOnL' delim delim xs)
      (m_ :: ms) => splitOnL' delim (m_ :: ms) xs
  else
    let (l, ls) = splitOnL' delim delim xs in
    (x :: l, ls)

splitOnL : Eq a => (delim : List a) -> {auto dprf : NonEmpty delim}
                -> List a -> List (List a)
splitOnL delim [] = []
splitOnL delim list@(_::_) = uncurry (::) $ splitOnL' delim delim list

substitute : Eq a => List a -> List a -> List a -> List a
substitute [] replacement = id
substitute (n :: ns) replacement = intercalate replacement . splitOnL (n :: ns)

strReplace : String -> String -> String -> String
strReplace needle replacement = pack . substitute (unpack needle) (unpack replacement) . unpack
```

I may try to submit a PR back to get this included in Idris' base libraries. **Warning**: I have not performance tested this, or even tested it rigorously at all; I have run it on about a dozen cases, and it seem right. If you just analyze the algorithm you will see it is not as efficient as you could wish. I have not succeeded at getting a more efficient version implemented while maintaining totality thus far.